# Power Query - How to decode values using two tables?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

How can we decode a master table like this

[image: Master table]

to decode values from codes table

[image: Code table]

to get the result like this in Power query/Power BI?

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the relevant information as text in the question itself, not as links to images. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a relationship between the master table and the coded table. But your coded table has 2 different types of data in it, gender and race. To create many to one relationships between the master table and the coded table, you probably have to split the coded table into two tables - gender and race.

[image: Gender]

[image: Race]

Setup the relationships:

[image: master - gender relationship]

[image: master - race relationship]

Use DAX to create new columns in the master table:

[image: Gender DAX]

[image: Race DAX]

If you cannot split the coded table, then you will need to import it twice, concatenate "gender"/"race" with the code, create the relationships between master and coded 1 and coded 2 and use DAX to create the columns in master.

[image: master]

[image: coded 1]

Comment: Many thanks Terry for the detailed description. But here both the files are connecting to web source and we prefer less manual intervention. Also how can we concatenate  the master table's header and data (prefix header with the data) like you have shown in the above mastertable screenshot (gendercoded contains gender1) automatically?

Answer (score 0):

split the code table into two as Gender code and race code, and relate them to master table.
[image: Table]
[image: visual]

Comment: Many thanks Praveen for the detailed description. Here in actual scenario the codelist contains 1000 of rows and the file is a websource. So can we split it into different tables? Also can we do this in Excel power query?